# Installing Visual Studio 2008 SP1 problem

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 but it tells me that "Previous releases of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008: Failed". I downloaded Visual Studio 2008 SP1 from here [VS2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en?), installed it (it said that the installation was successful), restarted the machine, but nothing has changed in Visual Studio Help -> About and the SQL Server 2008 Setup still tells me that Visual Studio 2008 is not upgraded to the SP1.

Does anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: I think this question should be asked in http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue several times. Visual Studio and SQL Server are heavily integrated, and I have botched many installations by installing things with special setups. It is probably easiest at this point to uninstall VS, install SQL, then reinstall VS.